# Android Change Geopoint Coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates

I was wondering if there is anyway to change a Geopoint's coordinates.  I couldn't find any functions in the documentation showing any way to set the coordinates except for in the constructor.  This is troublesome for me, because I'm needing to constantly update a Geopoint's coordinates (following an object on Google Maps).

If a Geopoint's coordinates can't be updated or changed, should I use something else?  Should I just constantly instantiate a new Geopoint?

Also, as a side question.  Where would I go about putting code that needs to be constantly looping (searching for data packets specifically) in a MapActivity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need a mutable `GeoPoint`? Are you sure that creating successive instances of GeoPoint is going to be a performance problem? Can you just keep the latitude and longitude in primitive variables, as Nate suggests, and only convert to GeoPoint as needed, or do you need each one to be a GeoPoint?

If you're certain you need a mutable GeoPoint, you can create one. The GeoPoint class isn't `final`, so you can extend it. But beware: putting mutable objects into a `HashMap`, `HashSet`, or any other hash-based collection will have surprising (and bug-ridden) results.

Take care you don't inadvertently pass one to an API that will put it in such a collection, even if you don't explicitly do so yourself.

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class MutableGeoPoint extends GeoPoint {
    private int latitudeE6, longitudeE6;

    public MutableGeoPoint(int latitudeE6, int longitudeE6) {
        super(0, 0); // the values in the superclass are moot
        this.latitudeE6 = latitudeE6;
        this.longitudeE6 = longitudeE6;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLatitudeE6() {
        return latitudeE6;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLongitudeE6() {
        return longitudeE6;
    }

    public void setLatitudeE6(int value) {
        this.latitudeE6 = value;
    }

    public void setLongitudeE6(int value) {
        this.longitudeE6 = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 29*latitudeE6 + longitudeE6;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return latitudeE6 + "," + longitudeE6;
    }
}
```

Edited to change the hashCode() method to be the same as Google's GeoPoint class.

(GeoPoint and MutableGeoPoint won't compare equal with equals. Worrying about things like that *quickly* reaches a point of diminishing returns.)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for the GeoPoint class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint):

> public class GeoPoint extends java.lang.Object
>
> An immutable class representing a pair of latitude and longitude, stored as integer
>   numbers of microdegrees.

The term **immutable** means it can't be changed.  So, you won't find any methods to change the values.  It doesn't look like a particularly heavyweight object, if you're worried about the overhead of recreating the `GeoPoint` over and over.  If you like, you could simply save the integer latitude(E6) and longitude(E6) values, instead of the `GeoPoint`.  Of course, `int` variables are mutable (able to be changed).

In any kind of `Activity`, you can create a worker to continuously loop and do whatever you want, with your own subclass of `AsyncTask`.  See [this article for a description of using AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: `int`s are not mutable. You cannot change the number 4 into a 5. You can assign successive values to an `int` _variable_, just as you can assign successive values to a `String` variable or a `GeoPoint` variable, but that doesn't make `String` or `GeoPoint` mutable.

Comment: @David, isn't that just semantics, though?  assigning a new value to an int primitive doesn't cause a constructor to run, or a new heap allocation to occur, which are the things people are usually trying to avoid when they complain about having to recreate new objects, instead of reusing existing ones, right?

Comment: That's true about performance. But the thing about immutable types is that if pass them to someone, they cannot be changed. In that way, an int is more like a String than a StringBuilder. You can assign many times to the same String variable, but each String value is immutable. So int has immutable semantics.

Comment: @David, who said anything about parameter passing?  Not I, nor the original question.  He was asking about changing/updating, not passing as parameters.  A caller's int passed into a method can't be changed, not because `int`s are mutable or not.  It can't be changed, because Java passes **everything** by value for method parameters.  I don't think the OP's brand new to Java, surprised that no method parameters can be changed.  He was surprised because he couldn't find a way to change a `GeoPoint`.  That's a question of object immutability, not parameter passing by value vs. reference.

Comment: @David, your first example comparing the assignment of ints to that of Strings is also fundamentally flawed.  When you assign a new value to a variable of type `int`, you can indeed change an int value (a 4 can get changed into a 5 at the memory location reserved for the variable).  When you assign a new value to a variable of type `String`, you are creating a new String, whose **value** is almost certainly stored in a new location ... and then changing the value of your String **reference** to point to the new memory location.  That's not at all what happens with assigning ints.

Comment: I was just using parameter passing as a convenient way of showing immutable semantics. When we talk about a type being immutable, we mean that values of that type cannot be altered, only replaced. That's true of ints; it would not be true of some MyInteger class with a getter and a setter. The fact that Strings are stored on the heap and int values fit in the same space on the stack as a reference to a String is an implementation detail that doesn't alter the semantics. When you assign 5 to an int that was 4, you alter the variable, but replace the value with a new value.

Comment: The other reason parameter passing is a useful way to think about it is because one of the key aspects of mutability is that you need to worry when you pass a mutable value to untrusted code, code you don't control. So, passing a StringBuilder, a List, or a hypothetical MyInteger class might be a problem; you might need to wrap the list in an unmodifiable list. But passing a String, an Integer, or an int is not a concern, because they're all immutable.